# How to get the results one property on two tables

Tags: php, php-5.6

residential_projects(table name)

```
id    City   Project_name

1      1     Residential Property 1
```

residential_units_details (table name)

```
id   residential_project_id  cityId  unitType  price
1            1                  1     1 BHK    50000
2            1                  1     2 BHK    100000
3            1                  1     3 BHK    150000
```

**Result i need like this**

```
Property id =1
1 BHK = 50000 (price)
2 BHK = 100000 (price)
3 BHK = 150000 (price)
```

I writen the query like this but i am not getting the correct answer ,how can do pleaase i spend more time on this please tell me solution 
**My query**

```
  $unitType = trim($_GET['unitType']);
  $first_second_tables = "SELECT * FROM residential_projects res_project JOIN residential_units_details res_unit ON res_project.id = res_unit.residential_project_id WHERE City='1'";
  if($unitType!='')
        {

            $first_second_tables .=" AND (unitType='$unitType')";
        } 

 $sql=mysql_query($first_second_tables);
 while($res = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
     echo "Proprty ID=".$res['id'].'<br>';
     echo "Unittype=" . $res['unitType'].'<br>';
     echo "Price=" . $res['price'].'<br>';
 }
```

i am getting answer

```
Proprty ID=1
Unittype=1
Price=50000
Proprty ID=2
Unittype=2
Price=100000
Proprty ID=3
Unittype=3
Price=150000
```

i think here printing all datas in second tables i don't know how to get my requirement answer anyone help me

**Updated code var_dump($res);**

```
array(3) {


["unitType"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["price"]=>
  string(5) "50000"
  ["Project_name"]=>
  string(22) "Residential Property 1"
}
array(3) {
  ["unitType"]=>
  string(1) "2"
  ["price"]=>
  string(6) "100000"
  ["Project_name"]=>
  string(22) "Residential Property 1"
}
array(3) {
  ["unitType"]=>
  string(1) "3"
  ["price"]=>
  string(6) "150000"
  ["Project_name"]=>
  string(22) "Residential Property 1"
}
array(3) {
  ["unitType"]=>
  string(1) "4"
  ["price"]=>
  string(4) "4343"
  ["Project_name"]=>
  string(21) "Residential Project 2"
}
array(3) {
  ["unitType"]=>
  string(1) "4"
  ["price"]=>
  string(4) "5353"
  ["Project_name"]=>
  string(21) "Residential Project 2"
}
```

Comment: Please explain more because your column create confusion & what is `res_project` in `select` query. Don't use `mysql*` function ti's is deprecated in php 5.5 & removed from php 7 ,prefer `mysqli` or `PDO`. see this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Comment: I have two table,proprty name stored in one table (residential_projects),and property price and unit type stored in another tables (residential_units_details ), i have one property and same property i have different unit type (BHK), now i want to display the results like 1 BHK means what is the price ,and 2 BHK means what is the price

Comment: I am written the join query for connecting two tables

Comment: try `var_dump($res)` see what value you want to arrange it

Comment: @ gaurav, please check my updated code for var_dump($res)

Comment: you want just  unitType & price for that right

Comment: Yes.still i am trying i am not able get answer

Comment: than why are you select all & get input from user which is unitType , try `SELECT unitType , price FROM esidential_units_details LEFT JOIN residential_projects ON residential_units_details.residential_project_id = residential_projects.id WHERE City = '1' `

Comment: Now i am getting unitType and price and also i want to display property name,it is in residential_projects tables how can display

Comment: Property id =1 or propertyname =Residential Property 1,
1 BHK = 50000 (price),
2 BHK = 100000 (price),
3 BHK = 150000 (price). i need answer like this

Comment: `SELECT residential_units_details.unitType , residential_units_details.price , residential_projects.project_name FROM residential_units_details LEFT JOIN residential_projects ON residential_units_details.residential_project_id = residential_projects.id WHERE City = '1'` try this

Comment: Ya i am getting but propertyname also coming in loop,while display the front end propertyname is heading and remaining details in loop like this i want to display,how can do this one please update your answer it will very help full for me

Comment: For me propertyname or property id no need for loop

Comment: can you update the `var_dump($res)` with current result

Comment: @ gaurav, please see my updated code for var_dump($res)

Comment: @gaurav can you please update your answer

Comment: i am facing problem  how to differentiate  `Residential Property 1` & `Residential Property 2` in loop

Comment: Hai gaurav now we can't get solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

SQL query for output is

```
 SELECT residential_units_details.unitType , residential_units_details.price , residential_projects.project_name  
 FROM residential_units_details   
 LEFT JOIN residential_projects   
 ON residential_units_details.residential_project_id = residential_projects.id  
 WHERE City = '1'
```

because you want only `unitType` ,`price`,`project_name` so no need to use `*`  for this you have to use `left Join` .

As you comment you want  `poject_name` on heading without repeating so you can try

```
$str = '' ; /* storing balnk string for matching */

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
      if(strcmp($row['project_name'],$str) === 0){  /* if the project_name already store it will return 0 */ 

        echo $row['unittype']," = ",$row['price'],"<br>" ;

      } else {
        echo $row['project_name'],"<br>";
        echo $row['unittype']," = ",$row['price'],"<br>" ;
        $str = $row['project_name']; /* here we are storing the project_name */
      }
    }
```